# Calling varargs method via DynamicMethod

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, cil, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I'm trying to call unmanaged printf-like function using DynamicMethod. At runtime I get a

> BadImageFormatException:Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131124)

Is this a limitation of runtime  or my emited code is wrong?

```
public class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt40.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int printf(string format, __arglist);

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var method = new DynamicMethod("printf", typeof(void), new Type[0], true);
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, " %s=%d\n");
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Program).GetMethod("printf", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var action = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I compared this to the IL of `printf(" %s=%d\n", __arglist("a", 0));` generated by the C# compiler, and which works. It's... exactly the same than what your code generates except for `maxstack`. That's weird, it's the same IL, it should work the same. :/

Comment: This actually works if I create an assembly, module and type manually (using the `-Builder` types) and then invoke the method. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the exception is exceptionally cryptic, I guess it is thrown due to some security checks related to calling varargs method, or it may be a bug in them. What works is to provide a logically associated type or module:

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("printf", typeof(void), new Type[0], typeof(Program), true);
```

Works flawlessly then.

Comment: Confirmed, it works. The [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.aspx) says *"In addition, JIT visibility checks can be skipped."*, looks like it's related.