# How to P/Invoke "__arglist" function?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, argument-passing

**Background:**
I have written the following function in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test(const char*, ...);
```

And I am using P/Invoke to call it from C#:

```
[DllImport("foo/bar.dll", EntryPoint = "test")]
public static unsafe extern int __unmanaged__test(byte* buffer, __arglist);
```

---

**Problem:**
I need to initialize the `__arglist` dynamically, meaning that I have an `Array<object>`, which I have to convert into the `__arglist` before calling the C++-function.

I have tried the following, but it returns an compiler error:

```
unsafe {
    byte[] buffer = ....
    object[] args = ....

    // ....

    fixed (byte* ptr = buffer)
        return __unmanaged__test(ptr, __arglist(args)); // <--ERROR
}
```

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

---

*for those who do not know what* `__arlist` *is*: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the C-style calling convention - the others (including the default Stdecl) don't support varargs:

```
[DllImport("foo/bar.dll", EntryPoint = "test", 
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static unsafe extern int __unmanaged__test(byte* buffer, __arglist);
```

Another tricky part is that `__arglist(...)` is a compile-time feature - it simply generates a (virtual) stack push for each of its "arguments". This means that you can't use it with arguments not known at compile-time - in your sample code, you're simply attempting to make a single argument, typed `object[]`.

Building the helper reflection methods isn't too hard - see [Calling varargs method via DynamicMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458616/calling-varargs-method-via-dynamicmethod) for an example. I cannot test this, but I'd guess `Expression` could be used to build this code easily - if you didn't have to pass that `byte*`, that is (do you *really* have to? passing `byte[]` could work just as well).

Comment: Thank you, but the error still exists. I think its the conversion between the array and the __arglist

Comment: @Unknown6656 Well, yeah, you can't do that. If you need to build `__arglist` dynamically (that is, you don't know the types and amount of arguments in advance), you'll probably have to use reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458616/calling-varargs-method-via-dynamicmethod for example.

Answer (score 0):

The comment [Luuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) wrote ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175822/how-to-p-invoke-arglist-function/32176032?noredirect=1#comment52238008_32176032)) had the solution I needed:

*quote*:

> If you need to build __arglist dynamically (that is, you don't know the types and amount of arguments in advance), you'll probably have to use reflection.
>   See [stackoverflow.com/questions/29458616/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458616/calling-varargs-method-via-dynamicmethod) for example